# Shell script - use variable in loop

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

I use following command for grant postgres db. It is working.

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = 'public';" performanceeyedev` ; do  psql -c "alter table $tbl owner to prodteam" performanceeyedev ; done
```

I write following script for grant postgres db. But it isn't working.

```
DB = 'performanceeyedev';
OWNER = 'prodteam';

for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = 'public';" $DB` ;
do  psql -c "alter table $tbl owner to $OWNER" $DB ; done

for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'public';" $DB` ;
do  psql -c "alter seq $tbl owner to $OWNER" $DB ; done
```

It make following result

```
./grant.sh: line 1: DB: command not found
./grant.sh: line 2: OWNER: command not found
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table dir_destinations_dir_dest_id_seq owner to 
                                                              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table dir_types_dir_type_id_seq owner to 
                                                       ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table dir_specialities_dir_sp_id_seq owner to 
                                                            ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table lb_report_types_id_seq owner to 
                                                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table too_many_submission_summary_id_seq owner to 
                                                                ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: alter table web_campaigns_web_camp_id_seq owner to
```

Please help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is not working? What is the expected result? What is the _actual_ result? Error messages? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/basic-bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found/2268117#2268117

Answer (score 4):

do not leave space between variable and '=' when assign a variable

```
DB='performanceeyedev';
OWNER='prodteam';
```