# Bash Variables containing filepaths

Tags: linux, bash, filepath, mv

I'm writing a script that needs to find a file in a directory based on the user input. That file contains a filepath, and I need to use that filepath as a variable so I can use it later in a mv command. So far :-

```
read x
path = `cat ~/filepaths/$x`
```

Later it needs to move a file from trash using the filepath read from this file

```
mv ~/trash/$x $path
```

Currently, it doesn't appear to work, and hangs when it runs. Is there something stupid I've missed here?

EDIT: Solved, was a stupid syntax mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/basic-bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found

Comment: It's "hanging" because `read` is waiting for input.  You'll get a syntax error on line 2 as soon as read gets data.

Comment: Also, you should consider using the `$(subshell command)` syntax instead of the `\`subshell command\`` syntax.  It's typically less error-prone.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: line 2 is a syntactically correct invocation of a program called `path` with argument 1 set to `=` and arguments 2 onwards set to whatever is in the file `~/filepaths/$x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the assignment:

```
path=`cat ~/filepaths/$x`
```

or:

```
path=$(< ~/filepaths/$x)
```