# sh script not finding variables

Tags: linux, sh

I am following a tutorial on how to run a reverse ssh tunnel which is found at http://wiki.fabelier.org/index.php?title=Permanent_Reverse_SSH_Tunneling Issue I am having is when I run the tunneling.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep`
if [ ! "$a" ]; then
    ssh -fN -R 19999:localhost:22 <middle-usename>@<middle-hostname>
fi
```

I receive this error:

```
tunnel2.sh: 2: tunnel2.sh: a: not found
```

EDIT:

I changed shebang to #!/bin/bash

now I get this error:

```
tunnel2.sh: 2: tunnel2.sh: pi: not found
```

Comment: Learn about the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, Sorry I still don't understand. Could you please help if you know the solution

Comment: What does /bin/sh --version say?

Comment: /bin/sh --version says 0: Illegal option --

Comment: /bin/bash --version is version 4.2.36(1)-release

Comment: I don't see any reference to `pi` anywhere in the supplied code.  What happens if you just type the commands on the command line instead of running it as a script?

Comment: @PaulTomblin from editing several times, I actually had a space line 2. line 2 was actually a= `ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep` not a=`ps -ef | grep 19999 | grep -v grep`. I don't understand the difference but that fixed it. I guess I will have to do some more reading

Comment: This might help explain the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/basic-bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found/2268117#2268117

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks William, That helped. bash scripting is a bit unforgiving.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't specify `#!/bin/sh` in your "shebang" line if you're going to use bash features.  If you want bash, ask for bash.

Comment: thanks Paul, please understand that I am knowledgeable in other languages but I am just starting out in shell scripting. I did try to change the shebang line as suggest but I get a new error as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Move the `!` out of the `test [` if you need sh

```
if ! [ "$a" ]; then
```