# awk command and variable assignment

Tags: shell, unix, awk, aix

I have a MyFile.xml whose contents are as below

```
<root>
    <Main>
            <someothertag>..</someothertag>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">13</Amt>
    </Main>
                .
                .
                .
                some other tags
    <Main>
          <someothertag>..</someothertag>
             <Amt Ccy="SGD">10</Amt>
    </Main>
    <another>
      <Amt Ccy="EUR">10</Amt>
     </another>
</root>
```

I have script file whose contents are as below

```
result = `awk '/<Main>/ { f=1 } f && /Amt/ { split($0,a,/[<>]/); s+=a[3] } /<\/Main>/ { f=0 } END {print  s }' MyFile.xml`
echo "The result is " $result
```

But i am getting output as

```
result: 0653-690 Cannot open =.
result: 0653-690 Cannot open 23.
The result is
```

My Expected output is

```
The result is 23
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/basic-bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found/2268117#2268117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning variables there should be no spaces on either side of the `=`.

Change to:

```
result=`awk '/<Main>/ { f=1 } f && /Amt/ { split($0,a,/[<>]/); s+=a[3] } /<\/Main>/ { f=0 } END {print  s }' MyFile.xml`
```