# Unix Variable Declaration

Tags: shell, variables, unix, scripting, grep

Hello I'm a total beginner in `shell` scripting.

I have a log file named `logA.log` and a `B.sh` file.

In log file there are some lines and I want to find the number of a spesific word in that log (in last 10 line) by executing the `B.sh`

**In B I wrote**

```
#!/bin/bash

variableString = tail -10f /home/appuser/logA.log

grep ERROR $variableString | wc -l
```

**but the output is:**

> variableString: command not found

I know "grep" line is working but I cannot reach the `logA in b.sh`.

How can I define a variable called `variableString` as last 10 line of `logA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `tail -f` ("follow") will not finish, so it never gets to the next line. You probably meant `tail -n 10` (the `-n` makes it [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tail.html)).
- You cannot use spaces around equals signs when assigning a variable.
- Variables are assigned to the string which the right-hand side evaluates to. Without special constructs, the result will simply be the **literal string** after the equals sign.
- You should [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) variables to avoid expansion.

In summary, you should use:

```
variableString=$(tail -10 /home/appuser/logA.log)
```

Comment: ahh yea that "-f" parameter killed me, gotcha thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your commands are ok but you have to be aware of the way to store command output: `var=$(command)`. Also, you may get several lines, so quote the return command to keep the format. Hence, you should use:

```
variableString="$(tail -10f /home/appuser/logA.log)"
grep ERROR "$variableString" | wc -l
```

When you get the error

> variableString: command not found

it is because as you define your syntax, `bash` interprets that has to execute the `variableString` command with the `= tail -10f /home/appuser/logA.log` parameters. See [Basic bash script variable declaration - command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268117/1983854) for further information regarding this.