# Assignment of variables with space after the (=) sign?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In Bash, assigning values to variables is done using `T=content`, with no spaces before or after the equal sign.

Despite that I've seen the following in a shell script `PWD= /bin/pwd`  containing a space on the right side of the equals sign.

What's the purpose of it have a space?

Comment: did you run the script and see what the PWD holds? It will be empty and you will see present working directory printed when you run the script?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the example `PWD= /bin/pwd`, the variable `PWD` is set to the empty string before executing the command `/bin/pwd`. The change only takes effect for that line.

This can be useful to make a temporary change to a variable for the purposes of running a command, without affecting the original value. Another example of this would be when using `read`, to set a different `IFS`:

```
IFS=, read a b c <<<"comma,separated,list"
```

This sets the field separator to a comma so that `a`, `b` and `c` are read correctly. After this line, `IFS` returns to the default value, so the rest of the script isn't affected.

Perhaps on some systems, the output of the command `pwd` is affected by the value of the variable `PWD`, so doing this prevents problems caused by `PWD` being overwritten elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe that's for different shells other than bash compatibility? That's the author explanation: `# The following circumlocution (repeated below as well) ensures that we record the true directory name and not one that is faked up with symlink names.`

Comment: Yes, from that comment, it sounds like it is possible that `$PWD` gets assigned an incorrect value in some cases and `pwd` will read this value if it is set, rather than work out the real path, on some other shells.

Comment: PWD is *not* unset.  It is explicitly being set to the empty string.   There is a difference.  For example, consider the difference between `${FOO-bar}` and `${FOO:-bar}`.

Answer (score 10):

```
PWD= pwd
```

This syntax assigns the empty value to the variable `PWD` for the duration of the `pwd` command.

```
PWD=ick
echo "$PWD"
```

This assigns `PWD` for the remainder of the script.

```
PWD=ick pwd
echo "$PWD"
```

This assigns `PWD` only for the duration of the `pwd` command; the `echo` will echo the value which was in effect before and after the `pwd` invocation.

```
PWD=
```

This simply assigns the empty value to `PWD`.

Pathologically,

```
PWD = ick
```

attempts to run the command `PWD` with the arguments `=` and `ick`

Comment: For what it's worth, by Bash's `pwd` command reports the current directory regardless of the value of `PWD`.

Comment: Incidentally, hardcoding `/bin/pwd` isn't usually necessary, and might be a bad idea. Scripts should trust the user to have a sane `PATH`, and allow for them to override system commands in some circumstances (mocking commands in a test script immediately comes to mind as one common scenario). Of course, here, you might want to ensure that any shell built-in command `pwd` is bypassed in favor of an external binary? But in the general case I would dissuade from doing this.

Answer (score 5):

We are not talking about two different things here.

If we had

```
PWD=/bin/pwd
```

we would assign `/bin/pwd` to `PWD`.

But

```
PWD= /bin/pwd
```

means that we call `/bin/pwd` with `PWD` set to the empty string. This assignment only affects the sub process, not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

When bash or most other shells see the below line:

```
PWD= /bin/pwd
```

the shell parses the command line from left to right. It breaks down the command line into two fields: `PWD=` and `/bin/pwd` since they're separated by unquoted space. When it goes back to parsing the first field PWD= it finds an unquoted = and so, shell treats it as a variable assignment/initialization. It thinks `PWD` as the variable name and any string immediately following the = sign until the space as the variable value. In this case, it would be an empty string since there is just a space after = sign and unquoted space is an argument separator in shell. So, `PWD` value would be '' (empty string) and by the way, this only affects the immediate command /bin/pwd as others have mentioned.

If there was a space before = as well, then shell would see 3 fields in total

`PWD = /bin/pwd`

Shell would treat first field `PWD` as either alias or function or command by searching in PATH locations. It would treat the other two fields `=` and `/bin/pwd` as arguments to the first command or function