# How to write result in empty variable?

Tags: linux, bash

How to write command result into empty variable?

```
#!/bin/bash
today=''
$today = $(date)
echo $today
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [There shouldn't be a space around the `=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971987/assignment-of-variables-with-space-after-the-sign)
2. On variable assignment, no need for the `$`

```
#!/bin/bash
today=''
today="$(date)"
echo "${today}"
```

Comment: 3. Remember to quote parameter expansions ;)

Comment: 4. If you can't find the error, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x`.