# bash urlencoded variable only echoes once

Tags: bash, urlencode

This is a simplified version of a script that runs with one parameter

```
#!/bin/bash
K1=eval /usr/bin/urlencode "$1" 
echo "$K1" # prints the correct url encoded $1 parameter
echo "$K1" # nothing printed
```

I looked at other more complex questions/answers to get why the variable lose its content

Moreover, without echoing `$K1` anytime, I lose its value if I try to use it in another value like `K2="zgrep $K1$DIR`. Echoing `$K2` prints `zgrep $DIR` value

Comment: cut-n-paste your code (along with shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommend change (ie, there's a problem with your `K1=eval ...` line)

Comment: `K1=$(eval /usr/bin/urlencode "$1")` is the correct way to assign the result to `K1`.

Comment: `eval` is likely not required, ie, `K1=$(/usr/bin/urlencode "$1")` should be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As running this with `bash -x` will readily reveal, the `echo` outputs the variable's value both times. You are assigning `K1="eval"` for the duration of the `urelencode` command, and its results are simply being displayed on standard output. Presumably `K1` was unset, so it then returns to an empty string; you are then running `echo ""` twice.

I'm guessing you were trying to say

```
k1=$(urlencode "$1")
echo "$k1"
echo "$k1"
```

This is a very common beginner problem. See also [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command), [Assignment of variables with space after the (=) sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971987/assignment-of-variables-with-space-after-the-sign), and somewhat more tangentially [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

`/usr/bin` should already be on your `PATH` so I can't see a good reason to provide a full path to the executable. If you genuinely have a different tool with the same name earlier on your `PATH`, probably sort out that problem instead.