# Script not executing properly.

Tags: linux, scripting, sh

I am writing a script in linux and when I run it, it seems like it is trying to run every line as a command?

My script is like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#add user script

clear
curUser = "$(whoami)"

Welcome to the user management application, $curUser.
1.)Add User.
2.)Modify User.
3.)Delete User.
4.)See Last 10 User Created.
5.)Quit
```

I did chmod +x Manage-Users.sh

ran it with ./Manage-Users.sh

my output is this : ./manage-users.sh: line 4: curUser: command not found.
There are a couple other lines with similar outputs.
Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic bash script variable declaration - command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/basic-bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the space before and after the assignment operator = ?

That line could be written as:
curUser="$(whoami)"

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us :-).