# Command sed using g

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting

I am new to Linux.
I was debugging some code.  I encountered the following command:

```
PROGRAM_ID=$(echo $PROGRAM_ID|sed 's/-/,/g')
```

Can anybody explain what the `g` represents here?
I understand hyphen is being replaced with comma.

Comment: Your original question had an unrelated syntax error which I edited out. You can't have whitespace on either side of the equals sign; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment

Answer (score 7):

The `/g` flag means, perform the substitution globally on a line.  Without that flag, only the first hyphen on every line would get substituted.

A better way with Bash would be

```
PROGRAM_ID=${PROGRAM_ID//-/,}
```

but if you have to be portable to Bourne shell in general, this replacement facility is not available.

(In which case you should take care to keep `"$PROGRAM_ID"` in double quotes in the `echo`.)

Answer (score 3):

Its easy to see how `g` (global) works with these two example:

```
echo "test-one-two-three" | sed 's/-/,/g'
test,one,two,three
```

```
echo "test-one-two-three" | sed 's/-/,/'
test,one-two-three
```

Without the `g` it only replace the first hit.

Comment: @MaheshPhate Tested and work on both Ubuntu and RedHat, works fine.