# get processor using adb inside bash script

Tags: macos, bash, sdk, adb

I'm trying to write a bash script (on my mac) that will get the SDK version and the name of the processor (and use it later) from an android device.
I assume the processor will be intel or arm.

so far, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "HI $USER" 

# get the sdk version
SDK = $(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r')

PROCESSOR = arm
# get processor type (arm or intel)
if ["$(adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo | tr -d '\r' | grep Processor | grep ARM)" = ""]
then
    PROCESSOR = intel
fi

echo $SDK
echo $PROCESSOR
```

and I get the following errors:

`line 6: SDK: command not found
line 8: PROCESSOR: command not found
line 43: [Processor : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l): command not found`

But when I write:

```
echo $(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r')
```

I see the correct version of the SDK.

can you plz help? I must be missing something because it should be super easy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the *spaces* before and after the `=` sign. For example change

```
    SDK = $(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r')
```

to

```
    SDK=$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r')
```

Do this for all the variables.

For more on this [Bash script variable declaration - command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found)

Comment: It worked! (also removed the spaces in the if statement), I knew it was something stupid.. Thank you very much! :)