# parameter allocation in a shell script within a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote the following  shell script

```
for i in mylist
do
cd $i
old = $(svn info | grep URL:)
echo old
done
```

but I get the following error message:

```
line 5: old: command not found
```

Hoe can I allocate the value obtained from `(svn info | grep URL:)` in a parameter.
I tried the following `echo$(svn info | grep URL:)`, that works but the allocation to old and then print the variable old dose not work.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces:

```
old=$(svn info | grep URL:)
```

Bash is sensitive to spaces in assignment.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found/2268117#2268117) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot  indeed but I can accept the answer in 10 min :)

Comment: Julian, do you know why dose this (DIRS=`ls -l $MYDIR | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'`
for dir in $DIRS  do    cd $dir  old=$(svn info | grep URL:)  echo old
done)  does not work?

Comment: No, I think you need to post a new question including output if you're unable to solve it. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot Julian I solved it :)