# Change variable and save it like another

Tags: variables, zsh

I have one variable:

```
>   lo=$(dirname "$(echo $FILES2 | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "} {print $1}')")
echo $lo  => /home/fil/Desktop/overeni_pipeline
> Rko_lo= $(echo $lo"/bam_files/")
```

and after that I received message:

```
zsh: permission denied: /home/fil/Desktop/overeni_pipeline/bam_files/
```

Could you tell me where is the problem? 
If I use it like superuser, I received message:

```
sudo: /home/fil/Desktop/overeni_pipeline/bam_files/: command not found
```

Thank you.

Comment: No spaces around `=`.

Comment: **Do not** use the bash tag if your shell is zsh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script variable declaration - command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is an additional space.

You wrote

```
Rko_lo= $(echo $lo"/bam_files/")
```

instead of

```
Rko_lo=$(echo $lo"/bam_files/")
```

This is the reason why the shell try to execute
the result of the `$(echo ...)` command instead of setting `$RKO_lo`
with it.