# Bash if statement not catching

Tags: bash, awk

Good afternoon,

im playing around with bash and wanted to write a script that would perform a traceroute and check if the second hop was a specific IP address.  below is my script:

```
Failover_check= traceroute 8.8.8.8 -n | grep 192.168.0.2 | awk '{print  $2;}'

if [ $Failover_check = "192.168.0.2" ]
then
    echo "ip found"
else
    echo "ip not ound"
fi
```

every time I run the script it always hits the else statement

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found

Comment: And [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the output of your command is not assigned to `Failover_check` variable. Use:

```
Failover_check=$(traceroute 8.8.8.8 -n | grep 192.168.0.2 | awk '{print  $2;}')
```

also; you might consider quoting your variables; to avoid errors when the variable is empty:

```
if [ "$Failover_check" = "192.168.0.2" ]
```

Comment: You beat me in seconds :P

Comment: @realspirituals: too slow :)

Comment: No need for double brackets or quoting the variable `if [ $Failover_check == "192.168.0.2" ]` should work fine.

Comment: @m0skit0 quoting is for safety; otherwise I get "unary operator expected" errors. You're right about the double brackets; I'll adapt my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assign it to the variable using $(...) and make sure no space before and after `=` that must avoid split and provide proper result

```
Failover_check=$(traceroute 8.8.8.8 -n | grep 192.168.0.2 | awk '{print  $2;}')
```