# Jenkins environmental variable sed

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, sed

I have an execute shell in Jenkins:

```
export MYVAR
MYVAR=echo $JiraReleaseNotes | sed 's/\[/<br>\[/g'
echo MYVAR=$MYVAR >> ./AndroidStable/App/config.properties
```

What I'm trying to do is replace all "`[`" values with "`[br>`" at `$JiraReleaseNotes` and set them to `MYVAR` and then copy the content to `config.properties` file.

But I get an error in second line:

```
Relase: command not found
```

Which `Relase` is the first word in `$JiraReleaseNotes`, why it thinks it is a command?

Comment: If you want to execute a command, you need to use `var=$(command)`. Currently you are saying `MYVAR=echo Relase ...` so this tries to execute the command `Relase` after setting the variable `MYVAR` to `echo`. See [Bash script variable declaration - command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2268117/1983854) for a great description of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script variable declaration - command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

You need to execute the desired command `echo $JiraReleaseNotes | sed 's/\[/<br>\[/g'` within brackets first before it can be assigned to a variable. As mentioned in the comments by [Fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) earlier, it will look like so

```
MYVAR=$(results_of_this_command)
```

in this case `results_of_this_command` or `echo $JiraReleaseNotes | sed 's/\[/<br>\[/g'` will be executed first, with the result of it then being assigned to be the`MYVAR` variable

**CODE:**

```
MYVAR=$(echo $JiraReleaseNotes | sed 's/\[/<br>\[/g')
echo "MYVAR=$MYVAR" >> ./AndroidStable/App/config.properties
```