# Saving awk output to variable BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to save an output of a command in a variable and then to use it. Currently.

```
newExtend= $(awk 'NR=='$cont $directy) 
echo $newExtend
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
newExtend = `awk 'NR==' $count $directory`
```

Those are backticks.

Comment: Those spaces around the equals sign are a syntax error, and the Awk command is no longer valid, either.