# Extract each line from a text file and compare it with all the lines in the file to avoid duplication in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

The content of text file text.txt

```
DS/Apple
DS/Banana
DS/Strawberry
DS/Apple
DS/Orange
```

The code that I wrote :

```
for i in $(cat text.txt)
do
    count = 0
    for j in $(cat text.txt)
    do
    if [ i == j ]; then
    count = count + 1
    fi
    done
    if [ count <  2 ]; then
    $i >> Final.txt
done
```

The error I am getting :

```
$ Trial.sh
./Trial.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./Trial.sh: line 12: `done'
```

I want the output without any duplicate lines in a new text file Final.txt

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yes, I missed fi.  When I correct that, I am getting an error again.

Comment: ./Trial.sh: line 3: count: command not found
./Trial.sh: line 10: 2: No such file or directory
./Trial.sh: line 3: count: command not found
./Trial.sh: line 10: 2: No such file or directory
./Trial.sh: line 3: count: command not found
./Trial.sh: line 10: 2: No such file or directory
./Trial.sh: line 3: count: command not found
./Trial.sh: line 10: 2: No such file or directory
./Trial.sh: line 3: count: command not found
./Trial.sh: line 10: 2: No such file or directory

Comment: Now you have many other issues... `count = 0` tries to run a command named `count`. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found/2268117#2268117) `$i >> Final.txt` tries to run a command named whatever is in the variable `i`.  `count = count + 1` again tries to run a command named `count`.  etc.

Comment: I want to use count variable to track the number of times the line is matching. If the line matches more than once then I want to discard the duplicates and form a new text file with out duplicates.

Comment: I am new to shell scripting and am not sure about the usage of variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' text.txt > Result.txt
```

This solved my problem. It removed the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all duplicates, you probably don't want to scan the file multiple times.  You can easily do it in one pass:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' text.txt
```

Comment: This is just an example file. It need not be the same Duplicate to use a regular expression. Moreover, even this command gives the output as :

Comment: $ Trial.sh
DS/Apple
DS/Banana
DS/Strawberry
DS/Orange
DS/Apple
DS/Banana
DS/Strawberry
DS/Apple
DS/Orange

Comment: @AmrutaMV I'm a bit confused by your comments, given that you indicate that this "soved my problem".

Comment: What was confusing?

Comment: @AmrutaMV  Are you saying that running this command (which is identical to the solution which you say "solved my problem") generates output in which the line "DS/Apple" appears twice?  That seems to be what your comments indicate, but that doesn't make any sense.  Hence, the confusion.