# Unable to put a output into a variable

Tags: bash, networkmanager

Currently I am having extreme difficulties when putting the output of a command into a variable.  I just have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
#! /bin/bash
on = $(nmcli networking connectivity)
echo "$on"
if [ "$on" = "full" ]
then
    nmcli networking off
else
    nmcli networking on
fi
```

edit: when I run this file I get nothing from the echo so I am assuming it is something going wrong with the outputing of the on variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
on=$(nmcli networking connectivity)
```

When creating and initializing variables, you don't have to put spaces before and after the "equal" sign.

```
if [ "$on" = "full" ]
```

The equal comparison on strings must be written with double equals: ==

Also be aware that your output can depend on system language!
Check this for cross-language support:
[HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105588/how-to-have-console-messages-in-english)

Comment: To iterate the reason why it works is because I used spaces between the variable and the $(command) believing that it would be like any other language, apparantly I was wrong and I should not leave spaces.

Comment: @FonzTech, you are wrong about the equality testing operator. [`=` is POSIX operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), unlike `==`. And in `bash`, `==` works identical to `=`. On the other hand `=`/`==` behaves differently in `[`/`test` and `[[`. In former case matches only identical strings, and in later case matches with glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two equals signs I.e. == for an exact conditional match

Comment: So what does echo $on return?