# Bash alias error with macvim

Tags: bash, macvim

Why the alias

```
alias vim= 'mvim -m'
```

is generating this error:

-bash: alias: mvim -v: not found

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after the = sign from your alias definition. Write `alias vim='mvim -m'`. It should work.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment) also for a detailed explanation.

Comment: It has solved my problem. Thank you!