# How do I pass BASH host command a variable and assign the answer to another variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if my DNS TXT entry has propagated so I wrote this simple loop, but I'm getting an error from the host command and I've tried many different syntaxes but all seem wrong.

```
while [[ ($basednsentry != $basehost) ]]; do
    $basehost=$(host -t TXT "$basednsname")
      sleep 1m
done
```

Comment: What error do you get? That would be necessary for solving your problem.

Comment: Also cross check if you have host utility installed on your machine.     which host

Comment: Remove the `$` before `basehost` on the second line.

Comment: The error I get is runcertirenew.sh: line 32: =_acme-challenge.domain.com: command not found

Comment: That's not from the host command.

Comment: I have installed host utiilty and the comman runs without issues from terminal

Comment: @codeforester I have declared basehost earlier, that's why I use the $ before it. However after taking it out, the code sems to work. Can you clarify why this is so and maybe add this as the answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: `$` is needed for expanding a variable, not for assignment.  In your code, shell is interpreting the whole expression as a command because of the `$` at the beginning.  Remove it and you will be good.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment

Comment: Be careful. If reassigning `basehost` is what you want, disregard my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what @codeforester commented, the problem was the $ sign left of the variable. The $ is not for assignment, but for expanding a variable. Furthermore in the link @codeforester provided there was a simple tool mentioned that immediately found this error in my code: http://www.shellcheck.net/

the working code therefore is:

```
while [[ ($basednsentry != $basehost) ]]; do
    basehost=$(host -t TXT "$basednsname")
    sleep 1m
done
```