# (In a loop) Command not found error in Bash variable assignment

Tags: bash, loops, variables

Why is this not possible?

```
        #!/bin/bash
        for (( j=1; j<=1; j++))
        do 
            DAA_$j=`echo A`
        done
```

I have already read [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment). But the answer I am looking for is not in there.

Comment: Generally, it's better form to ask "how can I do X?" than "why does the syntax I made up/guessed at intending that it do X (but without any supporting documentation/specification behind that assumption) not work?"

Comment: ...here, the "X" you're trying to accomplish (assigning to a variable name with a variable substituted into it) is implicit (described in your code, but never in the surrounding prose) -- but if you'd put that into your title, you might have had a duplicate presented by the site before even posting the question!