# issue to initiate a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

i made a function to parse my array. i've to send back two variable 
 -"$y" there is a match 
 -"$value" the name of the value

i dont understand why he dont want to initialize my res variable to y ?

```
 function contains() {
    local n=$#
    local value=${!n}
    for ((i=1;i < $#;i++)) {
        if [ "${!i}" == "${value}" ]; then
             res= "y" 
             echo "value of y : $res"
             echo "$res|$value" 
            return 0
        fi
    }   
    echo "no match found function"
    return 1
}



++ '[' 2017-11-16 == 2017-11-16 ']'
++ res=
++ y
./connectOracle.sh: line 53: y: command not found
++ echo 'value y : '
```

Comment: Do `res="y"`.  Remove the space after the = sign.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment/2268117#2268117

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: thanks i didn't see it :(

Comment: i dont understand why in my second function he dont receive my res params ?  if [[ $(contains "${arr[@]}" "$MEDIA_NDATE") == $1 ]]; then
            echo "match found $2 "

Comment: Your function doesn't print the value of `"$1"` so the condition is false. It's not entirely clear what you are attempting to do; maybe post a new question to explain what you are trying to do and where it is failing.