# why does the command line just goes to newline without error?

Tags: bash

[image]I have a problem with head command in linux when I assign a variable to it
like a=`date` and then echo $a I do get the result ! but when i use a= he ad date and want to echo result it just go to A new  line without any warning !why is it? how can I assign 2 command to be executed and stored in variable?
like

```
b= `banner date`
echo $b
```

Comment: @hek2mgl I think the second link was also relevant as it explains why `b=head date` works but `b= \`banner date\`` doesn't.

Comment: I see. Sorry if I wasn't careful enough. I think you can re-add it to the list.

Comment: @hek2mgl I am sorry, I don't know how to do that :) I will just post it here. I recommend checking out [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment).

Comment: why does it goes to a new line after I type echo $b (in the picture)?

Comment: @HodaFakharzadeh refer to the link in the comment above. `b=head date`  runs `date` with `b` set to **string** `head` in its environment. It is actually not a variable assignment so `$b` is still empty. Therefore when you `echo` an empty variable, it prints nothing + newline (`echo` appends the newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly,

"You can assign 2 command to be executed and stored in variable" as below -

`$ a=$(date ; uptime)`

Output -

```
$ echo $a
Sat Jan 20 18:17:54 IST 2018 18:17 up 1 day, 6:14, 9 users, load averages: 1.99 1.85 1.74
```

Comment: why does it goes to a new line after I type echo $b (in the picture)?