# Running curl command with JSON content from a shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the script below...

And I cannot seem to get the variables to work

```
#!/bin/bash

info = 'Help...?'    
object='{"attachments": [{"title": "ti1","text": $info }]}'    
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '$object' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx

exit 0
```

Even `--data '$object'` doesn't work without `$info`...as Slack API couldn't read my request.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net to catch the errors in your script.

Comment: @chepner: Can you find a proper dupe for this? I can't seem to find one in SO, only in Unix.SE

Comment: plenty of issues.. there shouldn't be spaces around `=` ... `$info` inside single quote - won't get expanded.. see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: @Inian for single/double quote --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for a long time I was tentative to use that link, I wanted to dupe with a definitive problem stating that single quotes won't expand the variable and double-quotes are needed. The one you shared is more detailed than needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment could also qualify, although in this case `info` actually *is* a command, which masks the error in the assignment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use double-quotes when passing shell variables and remove extra spaces in variable assignments.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "$object"
#                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Use nested quotes to preserve the value inside JSON syntax

```
info='Help...?'
object='{"attachments": [{"title": "ti1","text": "'"$info"'" }]}'
```