# Command not found error when passing filename to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, parameter-passing

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name = $1
ext = (file -b --mime-type $file_name | sed 's/application\///g')
echo $file_name $ext
```

Following error messages are seen while executing the code:

**file_extractor.sh: line 3: file_name: command not found**

**file_extractor.sh: line 4: ext: command not found**

I have tried  adding quotes to the variable, `file_name = "$1"` didn't work, 
then substituting `$(file -b --mime-type $file_name | sed 's/application\///g')`, using double quotes.

Nothing worked.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268104/608639).

Comment: Have you ever looked at a working shell script? Please don't try to learn a language by simply *guessing* at what you believe to be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in that script:

- Assignment to a variable does not allow for spaces around `=`

  ```
  var="val"  # OK
  var = "val"  # Not OK
  ```
- You are almost cetainly lookging for command substitution:

  ```
  var=$(something that produces output)
  ```

  Even though that is not the source of your errors. The former one is.

Comment: Thank brother !!