# Delete everything in string after "="

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cut

I have a variable `var` with value

```
backup = urls://string.abc.com
```

I want to exclude everything before `=` so that `var` has

```
urls://string.abc.com
```

I am using `var | cut -d "="` but it is not giving correct result

Comment: .. `awk '{print $3}'` ...

Comment: I believe the whitespace around the assignment of `backup = urls://string.abc.com` should result in failures; see [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268104/608639). Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Parameter Expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
var=${var/*=/} # Replace everything matching *= with empty string
```

or

```
var=${var#*=}  # Remove prefix matching *=
```

You can also do it with `cut`, but you need more code around it:

```
var=$(echo "$var" | cut -d= -f2-)
```