# Echo files names within a specific template

Tags: bash, echo, filenames

I have multiple files starting with the same name within a folder, but there are also other files. Let's say they start with 'plot'. I want to echo the names in such a template

```
"plot-abc";"plot-dcb";"plot-asd";...
```

There is no order in the rest of the names. I tried it with

```
for file in /home/user/*;
do
  echo '"'
  echo ${file##*/}
  echo '";'
done
```

but this is putting the quotation marks at the very beginning and the end. And can't eliminate the unrelated files.

I'd appreciate if we can find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) itself advises using `printf` instead in developing new code; see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` lets you provide a template, which is repeated as many times as necessary to process all arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- important: not /bin/sh; bash is needed for array support

shopt -s nullglob                 ## if no files match the glob, return an empty list
files=( /home/user/plot-* )       ## store results in an array

# if that array is non-empty, then pass its contents as a list of arguments to printf
(( ${#files[@]} )) && { printf '"%s";' "${files[@]##*/}"; printf '\n'; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This didn't turn anything. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: See `/home/user/plot-*` in the pattern.

Comment: sorry I just saw it. But it didn't return anything anyway.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the glob doesn't match anything. You'll need to adjust it to match files you actually have.

Comment: ...I can make the code a [mcve] that actually creates files before matching them, if you need such a demonstration that it would work if deployed correctly.

Comment: Ok, it worked now. For the code example I gave you, `/home/user/*` was working. But for yours, I have to change it to the name of the folder. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `/home/user/*` only looked like it worked because your quoting was wrong, and was re-expanding the glob *after* stripping the directory name... so when given an invalid directory name, it expanded the glob in the current directory instead.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) about side effects of using `echo $foo` instead of `echo "$foo"`

Comment: 1 more question related to this: I tried to declare a string variable such as

`sampleType = 'temp'`
and tried to implement this as
`files=( /home/user/plot-*${sampleType}* ) `

and then

`printf  'the file is'+${sampleType}`

.Can you tell me what is wrong with this? It says:

`sampleType: command not found`
`the file is+`

Comment: Doing that correctly would look more like: `sampleType='temp'; files=( /home/user/plot-*"$sampleType"* ); printf 'The file is: %s\n' "${files[@]}"`. Note that you can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment in shell; that expansions should always be quoted; and that `printf` data and format strings should be separate from each other.

Comment: BTW, you could have found existing knowledgebase issues about all those problems, if you searched -- see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment

Comment: That's great. Your are very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You are right. I couldn't see the issue and was close to be blaming `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. That's why I asked here, just in case.