# Count number of lines of a file and comparing

Tags: bash, shell

I need to count the number of lines in a file and then send a message depending if the number of lines is less than or equal to 20.
I am trying to do it this way:

```
touch file.txt
echo "hello" > file.txt
nr_lines = $(wc -l < file.txt)
if[$nr_lines -le 20]; then
  echo "number of lines is less than 20."
fi
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-le` means "less than or equal to" so the message "number of lines is less than 20" generally is not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment/2268117#2268117

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ on all your shell scripts.

Comment: The short answer is that you need a space after `[` and before `]`.  You should know that as a bash improvement, the `[[` and `]]` syntax was added for these conditional statements.  So, try this:  `[[ nr_lines -le 20 ]]` - you can even do away with the `$` in the `[[ ]]` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot right! There are just a few syntax errors in your code that make it not work.

1. Bash does not like spaces in variable assignments

   - Changed `nr_lines = $(wc -l < file.txt)` to `nr_lines=$(wc -l < file.txt)`
2. Bash LOVES spaces when it comes to boolean operators though! :)

   - Changed `[$nr_lines -le 20]` to `[ $nr_lines -le 20 ]`

```
touch file.txt
echo "hello" > file.txt
nr_lines=$(wc -l < file.txt)
if [ $nr_lines -le 20 ]; then
  echo "number of lines is less than 20."
fi
```

When things in bash don't work the *silly* syntax errors are often:

- Add/Remove spaces somewhere
- Mixup with `'` and `"` and `
- Forgot to escape a special character

Answer (score 5):

```
nr_lines = $(wc -l < file.txt)
if[$nr_lines -le 20]; then
```

This should be:

```
nr_lines=$(wc -l < file.txt)
if [ $nr_lines -le 20 ]; then
```

I'd use awk though.

```
awk 'NR>=20{exit} END{if(NR<20)print "number of lines is less than 20"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is safer

```
nr_lines=$(wc -l < file.txt)
if [[ ${nr_lines} -le 20 ]]; then
   echo "number of lines is less than 20."
fi
```