# Bash shell script to echo hostname and kernel version

Tags: bash, shell

```
     `hn = 'hostname'
      echo "Hostname: $hn"`
```

This is what I did for the kernel version as well, but this is giving me a two line output with the hostname on top and then "Hostname:" below. So how do I get the output to be "Hostname: " ?

Comment: `hn=$(hostname)` bash does NOT allow spaces around `'='` You can just `echo "Hostname: $(hostname)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(hn=`hostname`; echo "Hostname: $hn")
```

or  a more human readable format:

```
$(hn=$(hostname); echo "Hostname: $hn")
```

Comment: Good job for pointing out the preferred readability of *command substitution* with `$(...)` rather than backticks, `\`...\``.