# Bash: epoch time stored in variable pass into date command and make folder name

Tags: bash, date, variables, epoch, mkdir

I am writing a script that creates subfolders depending on epoch times included in file names.
here is a sample filename;

```
movie_lotr_frodo_1608020500_1608020510
```

desired output;

```
frodo/2020-12-15/movie_lotr_frodo_1608020500_1608020510
```

here is my script;

```
dir="/root/user/test"
cd "$dir"

for x in *; do
    name=`echo $x | awk -F"_" '{print $3}'`
    epoch=`echo $x | awk -F"_" '{print $5}'`
    hrdate=$(date -r "$epoch" +%Y-%m-%d)
    mkdir -p "$name/$hrdate"
    mv -- "$x" "$name/$hrdate"
done
```

I get the error;

```
date: 1068020510: No such file or directory
```

It creates `$name` folders but not `$hrdate` folders. Tried several things with date like `date -d` or unquoted `$epoch` but I don't know what am I failing at.

EDIT: I made some changes to scripts upon #tripleee's answer

Comment: i referred to this post in making this script; https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66494/434132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactored version with the following changes:

- Fix the [syntax error with the illegal space after `=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)
- Don't hard-code the directory; just run it in any directory you like
- Avoid unnecessarily calling Awk for extracting file name parts
- [Quote everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```sh
for x in ./*; do
    epoch=${x##*_}
    tail=${x%"_$epoch"}
    name=${tail%_*}
    hrdate=$(date -r "$epoch" +%Y-%m-%d)
    mkdir -p "$name/$hrdate"
    mv -- "$x" "$name/$hrdate"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a trailing space on the hrdate definition, it should be like this:

```
dir="/root/user/test"
cd "$dir"

for x in *; do
    name=`echo $x | awk -F"_" '{print $3}'`
    epoch=`echo $x | awk -F"_" '{print $5}'`
    hrdate=$(date -r "$epoch" +%Y-%m-%d)
    mkdir -p $name/$hrdate
    mv -- $x $name/$hrdate
done
```

Comment: I tried it as well but doesn't seem like have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found from `man` page to use `--date` and added `@`.

```
hrdate=$(date +%F --date "@$epoch")
```

`+%F` stands for YYYY-MM-DD format.

This worked for me