# mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My code is meant to find a /jar folder , loop through the .jar files and create .xml and .trigger files with the same file name. Additionally, it creates an ~ID~ filename ~ID~ field within the XML file.

I am getting the error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
```

I have the /tmp folder set up, including an /xml /jar and /trigger folder, so those not being there isn't the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

jar_dir= /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/jar
xml_dir= /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/xml
trigger_dir= /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/trigger       

# the following creates output directories if they don't exist

mkdir -p "${xml_dir}"
mkdir -p "${trigger_dir}"

# we start the for loop through all the files named `*.jar` located in the $jar_dir directory
for f in $(find ${jar_dir} -name "*.jar")
do
        file_id=$(basename -s .jar ${f})   # extract the first part of the file name, excluding .jar
       
      
        echo "<ID>${file_id}</ID>" > ${xml_dir}/${file_id}.xml
        touch ${trigger_dir}/${file_id}.trigger   # this one just creates an empty file at ${trigger_dir}/${file_id}.trigger
done
```

Comment: Don't put spaces around the `=` in an assignment. [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point this out, along with several other problems in your code. BTW, you really should be getting error messages from those `var= ` lines, that should tip you off that something's wrong there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
jar_dir= /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/jar
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
jar_dir="" /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/jar
```

and tells the shell to run the command `/c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/jar` with the environment variable `jar_dir` set to the empty string (only for the duration of that command). If `/c/.../jar` is a directory, that should give you an error, too.

To assign the `/c/.../jar` string to the variable instead, lose the space.

The error message you get comes from `mkdir` trying to create a directory with an empty name. (It's a bit confusing though.)

For problems with shell scripts, it often helps to paste the script to https://www.shellcheck.net/, which recognizes most of the usual mistakes and can tell what to do.

See these posts on SO and unix.SE for discussion:

- [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268104/6372809)
- [Is it shell portable to run a command on the same line after variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97302/is-it-shell-portable-to-run-a-command-on-the-same-line-after-variable-assignment)
- [Spaces in variable assignments in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258727/170373)

Answer (score 0):

`xml_dir= /c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/xml`
Can't have a space after the equal. So
`xml_dir=/c/Users/hi/Desktop/Work/tmp/xml`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, first point