# Function for rendering text in makefile

Tags: makefile

I create a function rendering input text(argument)

```
#Color renderning
define GPrint 
    kColorRed := "\x1b[0;31m"
    kColorGreen := "\x1b[0;32m"
    kColorEnd := "\x1b[0m"
    @echo -e "${kColorGreen}${1}${kColorEnd}"
endef
```

when I call this funtion

```
.PHONY : create_odir
create_odir:
    $(call GPrint "create output dir")
    mkdir ./output_dir
```

I got this error message

```
kColorRed := "\x1b[0;31m"
/bin/sh: line 1: kColorRed: command not found
make: *** [../src/sw/makefile:51: create_odir] Error 127
```

How do I solved it?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment/2268117#2268117 ?

Comment: @curleywei does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: Hi @Vroomfondel: I've applied your suggestion, then `kColorRed` is found. But output text does not change color.

Comment: This is because `make` invokes a separate shell process for each line in a recipe, thereby forgetting everything from previous lines. I completely forgot to mention this in my first comment, sorry. You can either write the whole recipe in one line, putting a `;`as command separator or the `;` and a `\ ` at the end of each line inside the `define` to mark it to be passed as one line to the shell processor by `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below code which will help you fix this issue.
**Method 1**:  Using global variables

```
# Regular Colors
kColorRed ='\e[0;31m'          # Red
kColorGreen ='\e[0;32m'        # Green
kColorEnd='\e[0m'              # Text Reset

# Color renderning
define GPrint 
    echo -e ${kColorRed}$(1)${kColorEnd}
    echo -e ${kColorGreen}$(1)${kColorEnd}
endef

create_odir:
    $(call GPrint ,"create output dir")
```

**Output** :
[image]

**Method 2**:
If you want to use local variables inside the function.

```
# Color renderning
define GPrint 
    $(eval kColorRed := '\e[0;31m')
    $(eval kColorGreen := '\e[0;32m')
    $(eval kColorEnd := '\e[0m')
    echo -e $(kColorRed)$(1)$(kColorEnd)
    echo -e $(kColorGreen)$(1)$(kColorEnd)
endef

create_odir:
    $(call GPrint ,"create output dir")
```

Comment: Seems can't use local variable in `define ... endef` Has a solution that we can use local variable within `define ... endef` ?

Comment: @curlywei I have added example  using local variables now. It will also give you the same output

Comment: @curlywei does the solution I provided works for you.

Comment: HI @Altaf: Good! Thanks! I recommend add `@` for each command inside `GPrint`, otherwise redundant command could be displayed on the terminal, such as `echo -e`. Could fix your code in Method 2? Thanks :)

Comment: @curlywei, wlecome:-). you can also use.SILENT to suppress commands