# Reassign value of $1 in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to reassign the value of the positional command line argument $1 to another variable to use elsewhere in the script, but it never works. I have put the following code in a new script and found that the value of the new variable is always blank.

```
dirname = $1
echo "This is \$1:$1"
echo "This is \$dirname:$dirname"
```

The output of this after running `./test.sh someval` is:

```
This is $1:someval
This is $dirname:
```

As you can see, 'dirname' is blank, even after being assigned the value of $1. I'm new to bash so likely missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the code **excactly** as it is in your script. If you really had a `dirname  =  $1` in your script, this would print a single period to stdout.

Comment: `dirname` is command name and cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: It is also unclear, what you are asking: In the title you ask how to re-assign the positional parameters in a script (this would be done using the `set` command), but in the text of your question, you ask how to assign something to a variable.

Comment: Moreover, assign to a variable can be done using `variable=value`, not `variable = value`.

Comment: @DaBler : You can use any command name as a variable name, as long as it is syntactically valid as a variable name. If this were not the case, you could simply break a working script, by putting a command with the same name as a variable into the PATH.

Comment: @DaBler It can; this just isn't an assignment statement. It's calling `dirname` with arguments `=` and the expansion of `$1`.

Comment: @user1934428 That is indeed true.

Comment: Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268104/1126841, except the attempted variable name *is* a command, so no "command not found" error is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignments cannot have whitespace around the `=`. An assignment is a *single* word containing a `=`: the name precedes the (first) `=`, and the value follows it.

```
dirname=$1
```